# Парсинг текста HTML Java

Tags: java, html, парсер

Есть текст:

```
<p>текст1</p>
<p>текст2</p>
<img ...><br>
<p>текст3</p>
<img ...><br>
```

и так далее..

Нужно составить список, каждый элемент которого - строка, находящаяся между тэгами с изображениями, то есть 1 строка - `текст1` + `текст2`, вторая строка - `текст3`. Не хотелось бы делать это в ручную, а как это сделать с помощью парсеров или регулярок я пока не догадался

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйся библиотекой [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download)

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("files/file.html"), "UTF-8");
for(Element element : doc.getAllElements()) {
    if(element.tagName().equals("p")) System.out.print(element.text() + " ");
    else if(element.tagName().equals("img")) System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод

> текст1 текст2
>   текст3

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), например:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

class HtmlParsingDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<html><body><p>текст1</p><p>текст2</p><img src=\"some.jpg\"><br><p>текст3<img src=\"another.jpg\"><br></body></html>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p");
        for(Element paragraph : paragraphs) {
            System.out.println(paragraph.text());
        }
    }
}
```

А можно и регулярным выражение

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RegexDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<html><body><p>текст1</p><p>текст2</p><img src=\"some.jpg\"><br><p>текст3<img src=\"another.jpg\"><br></body></html>";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(">([^<]*)<");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()) {
            String text = m.group(1);
            if(!text.isEmpty())
                matches.add(text);
        }
        for(String match : matches) {
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class HtmlParsingDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<html><body><p>текст1</p><p>текст2</p><img src=\"some.jpg\"><br><p>текст3<img src=\"another.jpg\"><br></body></html>";
        ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = doc.select("p, img");
        ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Element element : elements) {
            if(element.tagName().equals("p")) 
                text.add(element.text());
            else {
                texts.add(String.join(" ", text));
                text.clear();
            }
        }

        texts.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне необходимо объединить параграфы, находящиеся между тэгами с изображениями, как мне узнать какие из них с какими объединять, если в итоге я получаю просто список с параграфами?

Comment: Я показал в ответе общий принцип "как это сделать с помощью парсеров или регулярок", но вы, видимо, ждёте готового решения. Обновил ответ.